# Pointer to a vector of images

Tags: c++, image, pointers, vector, openframeworks

I'm working with openFrameworks to try and create a pointer to a vector of images that are stored in a class. I'm creating a sort of image sequence editor. There is a grid of images on one side and a viewer area on the other. A user can click on a grid cell containing a image sequence to display that in the viewer area.

In my GridElement header I have:

```
vector<ofImage> *getImages();
```

In my cpp file for GridElement I have:

```
vector<ofImage> *GridElement::getImages(){
    return &images;
}
```

This is a vector function to return a reference to the vector of images called images.

Then in my viewer class I am trying to access &images in order to display those images according to my viewer class.

I have done this with a for loop to load in all 15 instances of the object.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    viewImages = grid[i].getImages();
    }
```

That shows up no errors. Then I modulo though my images using variable currentFrame which is just an integer that keeps count.

```
currentFrame = (currentFrame +1)%viewImages->size();
```

When I then come to draw it in my display function

```
 viewImages[currentFrame].draw(504, 0);
```

This line doesn't work, error 'no member called draw'

Also tried to call it as a pointer but I get an error in Xcode saying it is not a pointer.

```
viewImages[currentFrame]->draw(504, 0);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your `GridElement::getImages()` returns a pointer to `std::vector<ofImage>`.
In that case the operator `[]` is used in a way to access an address of memory, NOT [the one provided by `std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/).

This:

```
viewImages[currentFrame].draw(504, 0);
```

should be:

```
(*viewImages)[currentFrame].draw(504, 0);
```

Comment: I tried the line `(*viewImages)[currentFrame].draw(504, 0);` But this resulted in a linker error. `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` Not too sure, why. Build succeeded then fails on that error

Comment: @Elliot The linker error is now no longer relevant to your original question. Also that linker error seems to be the error you actually needed to deal with. You should take a careful look at the way `OfImage::draw` is implemented. (Or whatever makes the linker lost in linking.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's start from simpler example, imagine you have `int` array:

```
int* pArray = new int[5];
```

What does compiler do when you write `pArray[3]`?

it does the following: *(pArray + (sizeof (int) * 3)), where returned value is an int.

So it does the same when you have `std::vector<whatever>* pVector`, and try to do `pVector[index]`. It treats `pVector` as `std::vector<whatever>` array, returning `std::vector<whatever>` object at the position defined by `index`, and I am pretty sure that `std::vector` doesn't have the member named `draw` (not to mention that you invoke Undefined Behavior, by using that pointer to vector like that).

Consider changing this:

```
viewImages[currentFrame].draw(504, 0);
```

to this:

```
viewImages->operator[] (currentFrame).draw(504, 0);
```

Comment: ofImage in openFrameworks does have a call to draw but yeah, not vector. I tried the line `viewImages->operator[] (currentFrame).draw(504, 0);` But this resulted in a linker error. `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @Elliot, I wasn't questioning whether `ofImage` has `draw` method, or not. And hence, it is not relevant here (that's why I used type `whatever`, as, up until the last 4 lines, the description of the problem, would be correct for any type), since you weren't trying to calling `draw` on `ofImage`, but rather, on `std::vector`.

Comment: @Elliot And, yet, you didn't post the actual linker error. Also, I tested my example on MSVC, and it compiled fine. After you mentioned this, I tried it on online C++ compiler, and it also [compiled fine](https://ideone.com/1WDY5X). So, I don't know where your problem is coming from (some unrelated code?).

Comment: The linker error is related to QuickTime. `ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime.tbd`

Comment: Using QTKit, which is deprecated in OSX 10.9

Comment: Not sure why I would get that error in relation to what I am doing

Comment: @Elliot So, that is not related to both of the answers that were given to you, and is separate problem altogether (not what your question is about).